# Malformed IP Address, new ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ip

I am installing a Ubuntu 13.04 from virtual disc over IPMI, yet when I come to manually configuring my network it tells me my IP address is malformed and should be in the format 'x.x.x.x' when it is.

My IP address is 192.186.137.050 (will remove if against regulations).

Why is this error appearing?

Comment: Does it work if you use `192.186.137.50` (with `50` rather than `050`)?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you put that as an answer and I will tick it. Sorry about that anyway. One other question I have is will it register as 050 even thought I typed in 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work if you use 192.186.137.50 as an IP ( with `50` rather than `050`)?

If it does it is either a broken sanity check in the installer or it tries to interpreted number starting with a 0 as [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers. If it applies that to all four numbers and any of those contain a digit larger than 7 it will error.